# Can redis scale well with 11 billion keys?

Tags: redis

My requirement is to store around 11 billion keys with no expiration and data needs to be persistent.Data structure used would be only hash and sets.Is redis advisable to be used for such high key requirement.If yes what should my setup look like ?

Comment: If you've got the memory for it Redis can probably do it. 11 billion keys is likely going to take a *lot* of memory. Test and find out for yourself. Instances with 128GB of memory can be rented by the hour for experiments, but running those long-term can get very, very expensive. Keep that in mind.

Comment: When dealing with such a large amount of keys, it is worth looking at special redis [structures](https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro) like bitops and (if a probabilistic approach is sufficient) hyperloglog. You might even write a redis module to store your data as small as possible.

Comment: @tadman I thought max number of keys redis can handle is 2^33

Comment: @WeihangJian Keys, yes, but with Redis you can jam data like this into one or more hashes, which uses far fewer "keys" but still has the ability to split out the data.